# How to add custom filter in salesforce dashboard

Tags: custom-object, dashboard, custom-report-type

how can i add a select box to select time period in dashboards, or in which way to proceed to acheive this
I added filter to dashboard, but im unable to set the filters for this month, last 6 months, and several time periods

Comment: its done, i used rolling filters in dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used rolling filters, so i add filters as this month, last 2 months, last 6 months like this